# Implementing OnActionExecuted on a custom ActionFilter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, actionfilterattribute

I'm currently trying to implement request logging for my WebAPI project. We're changing this to be async up and down. Consider the following example from our old action filter:

```
public class LogRequestActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ILogRepository _logRepository;
    private RequestLogEntity _requestLogEntity;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        _logRepository = (ILogRepository)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(ILogRepository));

        _requestLogEntity = new RequestLogEntity
        {
            LogDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Success = false
        };

        _logRepository.Add(_requestLogEntity);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        Exception exception = actionExecutedContext.Exception;

        if (exception == null)
        {
            _requestLogEntity.Success = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _requestLogEntity.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
        }

        _logRepository.Update(_requestLogEntity);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get away from using a service locator in my filters, by using passive attributes and filter dispatchers. I've been following [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98) example from Steven (the author of SimpleInjector). This is great for some of my other filters, and it works like a charm, I've managed to use this article to make a passive authorisation attribute/filter for example.

But now it's apparent that using this I lose the ability to capture the request when it is finished, ie. OnActionExecuted.

Comment: I hope this is daft question - you're creating `RequestLogEntity` in `OnActionExecuting` and updating it in `OnActionExecuted` - what lifestyle have you used when you registered `LogRequestActionFilter`

Comment: @qujck `LogRequestActionFilter` is an `attribute` on the controller

Comment: Ah, okay. That's not inline with the article you link to which describes separating the attribute (metadata) from the behaviour `IActionFilter<TAttribute>`.